# Creating different admin that everyone has permission to see only the products he enter

Tags: python, django

I want to allow different sellers to see only their products on their ADMIN site, add products that only they will see (except the general manager)
I attach the model of the products:

```
class Item(models.Model):
 ***seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)***
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=types.item_types.GENERAL)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=r'ecommerce/pictures', blank=True)  # adding date to the path?
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    sales = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Thanks to those who can advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here - the [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) and specifically [model admin change permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) check. It could be something like this:

```
class BankAccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj is None or obj.seller == request.user

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return Item.objects.filter(seller=request.user)
```

This will override the queryset and permission check to list/edit only records related with seller.

You may want to extend the logic to allow superuser list/change records or/and add some more specific permission.